How to Set Session Idle Timeout to One Hour in Keycloak?
I'm currently working on configuring Keycloak for our application, and I need to set the session idle timeout to one hour. I want the user sessions to remain active for up to one hour of inactivity before they are automatically logged out.
I've looked into the Realm Settings and Client Settings in the Keycloak admin console, but I'm a bit confused about which specific settings to adjust and how to ensure this configuration applies correctly.As we have tried configuring below settings and our webapp(nextjs) gets log out screen after 40 mins when we left it as idle for testing idle timeout.
Client session idle : 1 hr
SSO session idle: 8 hr
Access token : 15 min
Could someone provide detailed steps on how to set the session idle timeout to one hour in Keycloak? Any additional tips or best practices for managing session timeouts in Keycloak would also be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
